# SQL - selecting from multiple tables where one table returns no results

Tags: mysql

I have two tables in my database

```
- billing_supplier_invoices
- billing_payments
```

There are multiple records in `billing_payments` for each 1 record in `billing_supplier_invoices` and `billing_supplier_invoices.sequence = billing_payments.seq`

i want to be able to select all records from `billing_supplier_invoices` where the sum of all records (`billing_payments.amount`) does not equal `billing_supplier_invoices.grand_total`

i have tried something like this:

```
Select billing_supplier_invoices.* 
from billing_supplier_invoices 
LEFT JOIN billing_payments 
     ON 
billing_supplier_invoices.sequence = billing_payments.invoice_sequence 
where type = 'Supplier' 
and billing_supplier_invoices.grand_total <> sum(billing_payments.amount)
```

but i get an SQL error saying

> **Error:** **invalid use of group commands**

Comment: Would you little bit explain you `and` condition ? what are you looking for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used this code in PHP and used a while loop for one table

i then use a single query inside the while loop to select from the second table as the query i wanted to run was going to end up saying `where col1 > NULL` in the first query

Answer (score 0):

```
Select  billing_supplier_invoices.*
From 
billing_supplier_invoices 
LEFT JOIN  billing_payments ON
billing_supplier_invoices.sequence = billing_payments.seq
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    SELECT * FROM billing_supplier_invoices 
WHERE billing_supplier_invoices.grand_total 
<>( SELECT sum (billing_payments.amount) 
FROM billing_payments 
WHERE billing_supplier_invoices.sequence = billing_payments.seq 
GROUP BY billing_payments.seq)
```

Comment: ok so i have a row in billing_supplier_invoices (sequence = 4, grand_total = 10) and a row in billing_payments (seq = 4, amount = 10) when i run the above query this row is still showing

Comment: there may be more records with seq=4 in billing_payments .Post result for SELECT *
 FROM billing_payments 
 WHERE billing_payments.seq ='4'

Comment: the sum of `billing_payments.amount` equals 10 which is the same as `billing_supplier_invoices.grand_total` therefore the row should not display because both values are equal. if `billing_payments.amount` sum equaled 9 then the row should display

Comment: there is not - this is the only record

Comment: What does this give you SELECT * FROM billing_supplier_invoices WHERE billing_supplier_invoices.sequence ='4'

Comment: ok this is working http://pastebin.com/mTwkHb8Y if there are rows in billing_payments where the grand_total is > sum amount but if no rows exist in billing_payments nothing is returned